# Add cell copy to existing function

Tags: google-apps-script

From within the following code, what can i add to the function to make it also copy specific cells from the Sales sheet into different cells of the Man sheet?

```
   function CreateManCopyOfTemplateFromActiveSalesFile() {         
 var copyMan = DriveApp.getFileById("Man. Template").getId();    
 var toFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("Man. Folder");       
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 var sheetName = sheet.getRange('B3').getDisplayValue();

 DriveApp.getFileById(copyMan).makeCopy(sheetName, toFolder);  }
```

This function works to Take name of Active sheet (SalesFile), apply it to copy of different Sheet( Man.File) and put this template copy into a different,specified Folder containing all the other Man files.

We want to also copy Several cell values over to the newly copied and named Man. File and put those values into different cells than the ones they came from in the source (SalesFile). Can this be done or is it really two separate functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function CreateManCopyOfTemplateFromActiveSalesFile() {         
  var srcId="Man. Template";    
  var desfldr=DriveApp.getFolderById("Man. Folder");       
  var srcsh=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var desshname=srcsh.getRange('B3').getDisplayValue();
  var desfile=DriveApp.getFileById(srcId()).makeCopy(desshname, desfldr);  
  var srcrgA=['B4','B5','B10','D11','E4'];
  var desrgA=['B8','B10','D15','E3','J14'];
  var src=SpreadsheetApp.openById(srcId);
  var des=SpreadsheetApp.openById(desfile.getId());
  var dessh=des.getSheets()[0].getName();
  srcrgA.forEach(function(sA1,i){
    dessh.getRange(desrgA[i]).setValue(srcsh.getRange(sA1).getValue());
  });
}
```

Comment: Your code worked with one tiny mod. I thank you. I appreciate your help and wish there was a way we could talk. I've accepted your answer, will do anything to help your rep and, wish you the best!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
function CreateManCopyOfTemplateFromActiveSalesFile() {         
  var srcId="Man. Template";    
  var desfldr=DriveApp.getFolderById("Man. Folder");       
  var srcsh=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var desfilename=srcsh.getRange('B3').getDisplayValue();
  var desfile=DriveApp.getFileById(srcId()).makeCopy(desfilename, desfldr);  
  var srcrgA=['B4','B5','B10','D11','E4'];
  var desrgA=['B8','B10','D15','E3','J14'];
  var des=SpreadsheetApp.openById(desfile.getId());
  var dessh=des.getSheetByName(srcsh.getName());
  srcrgA.forEach(function(sA1,i){
    dessh.getRange(desrgA[i]).setValue(srcsh.getRange(sA1).getValue());
  });
}
```